# Difference between text filter types?

Tags: 8, input-formats

When creating text filter, there are several "type" options ([see here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!filter!src!Plugin!FilterInterface.php/interface/FilterInterface/8.2.x)). What is the difference between these two?

```
FilterInterface::TYPE_TRANSFORM_IRREVERSIBLE: Irreversible transformation filters.
FilterInterface::TYPE_TRANSFORM_REVERSIBLE: Reversible transformation filters.
```

Are there some examples when to use them? For example, when I add a class to a HTML element without any class or specific attribute, is that reversible or irreversible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per the [Filter API](https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/8/filter) docs:

> - Every filter plugin must specify a filter type in its annotation. Filter types were added specifically to support in-place editing. There are four filter types:
>
>   1. `FilterInterface::TYPE_MARKUP_LANGUAGE` — Non-HTML markup language filters that generate HTML. The filter converts something that's not HTML to HTML in a way that is not compatible with WYSIWYG editing.
>   2. `FilterInterface::TYPE_HTML_RESTRICTOR` — HTML tag and attribute restricting filters to prevent XSS attacks. The filter restricts the HTML allowed, for example, to protect against XSS.
>   3. `FilterInterface::TYPE_TRANSFORM_REVERSIBLE` — Reversible transformation filters. The filter performs a transform for which a WYSIWYG plugin exists to perform the same transformation (and its reverse) client-side. For example, `<img data-caption="Druplicon">` may be (reversibly!) transformed to `<figure><img><figcaption>Druplicon</figcaption></figure>`.
>   4. `FilterInterface::TYPE_TRANSFORM_IRREVERSIBLE` — Irreversible transformation filters. The filter performs a transform for which a WYSIWYG plugin does not exist to perform the transformation client-side (especially, the reverse of it); instead, the WYSIWYG editor displays the unfiltered text. For example, Token Filter.

The type examples given are pretty descriptive of when to use them.

If you **CAN** take the filtered output and put it back into its original form via a WYSIWYG plugin (e.g. structured markup like XML -> JSON -> XML), use `FilterInterface::TYPE_TRANSFORM_REVERSIBLE` because the filter output can be reversed.

If you **CANNOT** take the filtered output and put it back into its original form via a WYSIWYG plugin(e.g. a token filter that prints the node title), use `FilterInterface::TYPE_TRANSFORM_IRREVERSIBLE` because the filter output cannot be reversed.